# I want my function to return TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the population goes extinct up to the maximal time

Tags: r

I have written a function but now we ask me to return true or false  depending on whether the population goes extinct up to the maximal time and I'm a bit lost on how to do it, here is my function :

```
 stochasticGrowth = function(initN, b, d, K) {
  beta = delta = 0.5*(b-d)/log(K)
  N = c(initN)
  for (t in 1:maxT) {
    currentN = tail(N, 1)
    if (currentN > 0) {
      births = sum(rpois(currentN, b-beta*log(currentN)))
      pDeath = d + delta*log(currentN)
      deaths = sum(sample(c(T,F), currentN, p=c(pDeath, 1-pDeath), replace=T))
      N = c(N, currentN + births - deaths)
    } else {
      N = c(N,0)
    }
  }
  return(N)
```

Comment: i would do an ifelse ::  if the pop size at Tmax is greater than 0 , survived=True , else survived = FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `while` loop that increases a counter (`t`) if `N>0`
, then returning that counter.

```
stochasticGrowth = function(initN, b, d, K) {
  beta = delta = 0.5*(b-d)/log(K)
  N = c(initN)
  t = 0
  while(N>0){
    t = t+1
    currentN = tail(N, 1)
    if (currentN > 0) {
      births = sum(rpois(currentN, b-beta*log(currentN)))
      pDeath = d + delta*log(currentN)
      deaths = sum(sample(c(T,F), currentN, p=c(pDeath, 1-pDeath), replace=T))
      N = c(N, currentN + births - deaths)
    } else {
      N = c(N,0)
    }
  }
  return(t)
```

Comment: I want my function to tell me how much time will it take for population to go extinct

Comment: I can give what  we want me to do for the entire exercise if you want maybe it will help to understand.

Comment: Check my edit !